# Cannot find interface declaration for 'OS_dispatch_queue'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Cannot find interface declaration for 'OS_dispatch_queue'
How to fix this Semantic Issue in Project-swift.h file ?
Xcode 12.2
The error is coming after updating iOS version in Targets -> General -> Deployment Info to iOS 11.0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xGdc.png)

Comment: Did you find an answer ? having the same issue...